# How are multiple matches handled for waitForObject?

Tags: squish

I didn't find any statement in the Squish documentation about this: How is it handled in `waitForObject` (and other functions) if there are multiple matches for a given pattern?

Is the first entry returned or does this result in a LookupError?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `waitForObject` function will return the first object matching the pattern. But this will only be a problem if the pattern is underspecified. To select a particular object from a sequence of identical objects the *occurrence* property can be used.

The `Object Picker` and script recorder will calculate the right *occurrence* property automatically by the way.

The tool's [Knowledge Base](https://kb.froglogic.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=131141) has some more background information.